# Process getting suspended automatically

Tags: linux, macos, visual-studio-code, process, operating-system

I'm doing my usual npm run start and just after a few seconds, it suspends it automatically.

Machine: Mac M1 Air

I tried but didn't find any similar issue on the internet.
Please help!
Do let me know if any additional information is needed.

It seems it's not a code-related issue as I'm facing it in both the react and node apps. As seen in the attached Screenshots.

REACT APP
[image]

NODE APP

[image]

Comment: run in debugger, determine where code is generating a signal?

Comment: @stark actually, I don't think it's related to code you know. Since today while I was running my node app even there I got the same issue so I don't think it's a code-related issue. That's why I tagged it as macOS, processes, vscode, etc